# Solve $\vert i+2i^2+3i^3+...+ni^n\vert$=$18\sqrt 2$ for $n$, where $i^2=-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation

> Suppose $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\vert
>  i+2i^2+3i^3+...+ni^n\vert$=$18\sqrt 2$.Where $i$ is a square root of
>   $-1$.Then what is the value of $n$?

Solution: Let $S_n=i+2i^2+3i^3+...+ni^n\tag{1}$

Then  $iS_n=i^2+2i^3+3i^4+...ni^{n+1}\tag{2}$

Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$, we get

$$S_n(1-i)=(i+i^2+i^3+...+i^n)-ni^{n+1}$$ hence $$S_n=\frac{i(1-i^n)}{(1-i)^2}-\frac{ni^{n+1}}{1-i}=\frac{i(1-i^n)}{-2i}-\frac{ni^{n+1}}{1-i}$$

This is where I get stuck.

Comment: @Servaes ?? Did you see that $S_n$ is the sum of *two* terms?

Comment: @Servaes:I'm not getting your question

Comment: Using $2S_n=ni^n(1-i)+i^n-1$ and solving separately the four congruences of $n$ modulo $4$ seems to bring the solutions $n=35$ and $n=36$. Not a very elegant approach though...

Comment: @Did:Is'nt any way to proceed further where i left this question?The approach you suggested is nice one but it requires  lots of calculations.

Comment: @Did:If $z_1=\frac{i(1-i^n)}{-2i}$,then $\vert z_1\vert=0$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ accordingly if $n$ is a multiple of $4$ or otherwise. and if $z_2 =\frac{ni^{n+1}}{1-i}$,then $\vert z_2\vert =\frac{n}{\sqrt 2}$.Now on evaluating both cases i'm getting $n=35 & 36$.

Comment: @Did:Am i correct?

Comment: What is the argument when $n$ is not a multiple of $4$, exactly? You would not use the (wrong in general) identity $|z_1+z_2|=|z_1|+|z_2|$, would you?

Comment: KVPY right .........

Comment: @dp1611:Assignment problem from an olympiad exam in India,just exercising my mind.

Comment: yes its from kvpy sx stream

Answer (score 1):

$18\sqrt 2$ is possible if and only if our solution is of form ${|\pm18 \pm18i| }$ (as we have terms in sequence)("if and only if"-part comes from the fact that ${a^2+b^2=18^2*2}$ has only integer solutions ${a,b}$ are ${\pm18}$)

So our real part should be ${\pm18  }$ and imaginary part should be ${\pm18i }$

Now solving, for real part:

-2+4-6+8... = 18 if last term is 36

or

-2+4-6+8... = -18 if last term is -34

For imaginary part:

1-3+5-7...=-18 if last term is -35

So n=36(or 35 depending on you take sum of reals to be +18 or -18)

Comment: Might be good to mention that the "if and only if"-part comes from the fact that $a^2+b^2 = 18^2*2$ has the only integer solutions $a, b \in \{\pm 18\}$.

Comment: This misses some solution and is peppered with unproven statements. (Additionally, note that "QED" at the end is odd since we are not asked to prove a specific statement...)

Comment: @Sagar Chand:how can you conclude that last term is 36?

Comment: I doubt I missed some solutions, and the fact stated by @pepa.dvorak that only one set of solution exists proves that no solution has been missed.

Comment: @PK Styles:If you start taking sum, and pair them together, you will see that each pair adds 2. eg(-2+4)+(-6+8) and so on. Since we need 18, last term has to be 36. Similarly for imaginary case

Comment: There are **two** solutions, as Did already said, $n \in \{35,36\}$

Comment: By the way, could you **prove** (you know, rather than simply *assert*) that $a^2+b^2=2\cdot18^2$ implies $a^2=b^2=18^2$? 'Cause the whole solution relies on this trick...

Comment: @Did These are only integers which satisfy this equation.

Comment: Again: **why?** At this point, it seems clear that you have no idea to prove this...

Comment: For example, $$1^2+7^2=2\cdot5^2$$ hence a proof **is** necessary (and some elementary versions exist, but none of them is in this "answer").